# Visual Studio Charts

Tags: html, sql, database, visual-studio-2015, web

We are designing a website on Visual Studio 2015 and we're adding charts and graphs to the page. Two questions:

1. When creating a graph, how do we get it to show only the last 7 rows?
2. How to compare fields of one row (record) in a pie graph?

We're using SQL.

[image: database example]

Answer (score 0):

For your 1 question

```
Select top 7 * from MyTable 
order by Id desc
```